# unlinked clang - compiler error (MacOS)

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-errors, clang, unlink

I tried to replace "clang" with gcc. 
At the last step I executed the command "sudo unlink ...".
"clang" and "clang++" (in /usr/bin/).

Now the compiler gives this error:
/usr/include/stdio.h:64:2: Malformed or corrupted AST file: 'mismatched umbrella directories in submodule'

How do i reset "clang" and "clang++"?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try the obvious: reinstalling xcode?

Comment: Uh, the same way you installed it the first time?

Comment: no way, there is no remove option in apple store

Comment: Replace clang by gcc... Usually, it's in the other way... Curious about the reason...

Comment: @Furtano You can remove it from the launchpad...

Comment: @Macmade no way to remove it without new installtion of the OS. I had to replace clang with gcc because clang does not support OpenMP which is very important for me and i think widespread.

Answer (score 0):

I installed MacOS new with the Rescue-Partition of MacOS (Press alt while starting and then select the Recovery Partition). Now all works fine.